# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open directory at Error (native) when upload image

Tags: node.js, multer

i want to upload an image using multer, but when i change my **app.js**, i have tried many solution but didnt work for me :(

```
var multer = require('multer');
var path = require('path');
var id_photo = uuidv1();

global.appRoot = __dirname;

var storage = multer.diskStorage({

destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads')
},
filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + id_photo + path.extname(file.originalname));
}
})

var upload = multer({
storage: storage,
fileFilter: function(req, file, callback) {
    var ext = path.extname(file.originalname)
    if (ext !== '.png' && ext !== '.jpg' && ext !== '.gif' && ext !== '.jpeg') {
        req.fileValidationError = "Only Image Allowed";
        return callback(null, false, req.fileValidationError)
    }
    callback(null, true)
}
}).any();

app.use(upload);
connection.init();
```

to

```
var multer = require('multer');
var path = require('path');

global.appRoot = __dirname;

var storage = multer.diskStorage({

destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads')
},
filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    var id_photo = new Date();
    var dd = id_photo.getDate();
    var mm = id_photo.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = id_photo.getFullYear();
    var h = id_photo.getHours();
    var i = id_photo.getMinutes();
    var s = id_photo.getSeconds();
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }

    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm
    }

    if (h < 10) {
        h = '0' + h
    }

    if (i < 10) {
        i = '0' + i
    }

    if (s < 10) {
        s = '0' + s
    }
    id_photo = mm + '-' + dd + '-' + yyyy + '-' + h + ':' + i + ':' + s;
    callback(null, id_photo + "*-" + file.originalname);

}
})

var upload = multer({
storage: storage,
}).any();

app.use(upload);
connection.init();
```

i get an error like this

**Error:**

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Nodejs\nodejs-wmc\uploads\04-11-2018-13:20:09*-8.jpg'
>       at Error (native)

whereas file uploads already exist, when i use app.js the first runs smoothly. what wrong with my code?

please help me ... thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using reserved characters in your path. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247 following symbols are reserved on Windows:

```
< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon)
" (double quote)
/ (forward slash)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
```

It should work fine if you change your path format to:

```
id_photo = mm + '-' + dd + '-' + yyyy + '-' + h + '_' + i + '_' + s;
callback(null, id_photo + "-" + file.originalname);
```